# Запрос данных из связанных таблиц и получение из них результата

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть 2 таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE `profile` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` text NOT NULL,
  `last_name` text NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` text NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid_key` varchar(128) NOT NULL
)
```

и

```
CREATE TABLE `position` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text
)
```

Profile.position связан с position.id

Я выполняю запрос

```
SELECT profile.* 
from profile 
inner join position ON profile.position = position.id
```

и получаю id таблицы position

### Как убрать position.id из запроса

Comment: Как... встречный вопрос - зачем? При нормальной организации системы внутренний номер записи - он "ниачём", и его знание третьей стороной никакой угрозы не несёт.

Answer (score 2):

Указать явно список полей

```
SELECT profile.first_name from profile inner join position ON profile.position = position.id
```